# propagation of standard error in a sum of proportions

Tags: error-propagation

I am new to error propagation, and I am trying to solve a simple problem:

I am trying to  calculate the estimate and standard error of a parameter (carbon density) across a landscape composed of three landscape types, $L_1, L_2, L_3$, each of which has an estimated C density $C_1, C_2, C_3$ and standard error of the mean ($se_1, se_2, se_3$), and is present in proportion $P_1, P_2, P_3$ where $\sum_{i}{P_i} = 1$. The estimate of the total landscape C density (per unit) is $$\sum_{i}{C_{i}P_{i}}$$ but what is the standard error? Something like? $$\sqrt{\sum_{i}{P_{i}se_{i}^2}}$$ Thanks!

Comment: **Final followup**. Done more reading, not really sure about this. Perhaps one day I will figure out the answer and be able to report it here. Deleted previous answer I thought was correct at the time as I do not want to spread bad information.